# Rails 4 not processing migration variables

Tags: postgresql-9.3, ruby-on-rails-4.2

A rails 4.2 migration creates three new variables.  Querying postgresql

```
\d+ table
```

lists these variables correctly

```
 payment_direct               | numeric                    |                                                           | main     |              | [...]
```

the class controller permits each of these params, which is confirmed by the console as it has no `unauthorized params` message.  The console indicates processing of the parameter

```
INSERT INTO [...] ["payment_amount", "44.238"], ["payment_direct", "42.8"]
UPDATE [..] ["payment_amount", "44.238"], ["payment_direct", "42.8"]
COMMIT
```

with no complaints.

The best part is that the controller is acting upon the parameter to calculate another param before the `Transact.new(transact_params)` statement

```
params[:transact][:payment_amount] = (params[:transact][:payment_direct].to_d * markup) + fixed
```

and saving the calculated param.

What is missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong structurally. More of a quirk in development mode.

Required `exit` then re-boot console `rails c`.  Restarting the server alone is insufficient.  So it appears the console loads and holds onto a data structure at start and accesses on-going data with the old structure.